# ASP.NET Session Values Not Being Carried to a Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I have a simple ASP.NET C# web page; lets say default.aspx. In that there is a button; clicking on that button does the following in the code behind:

```
Session["groupid"] = 1;
```

and the value of 1 actually shows on a text box. So far so good. Then I also have a Web Service in .asmx file in the same level as the default.aspx page. That web service is being called by a Jquery Ajax function. What I am trying to do is to do some sql queries using the session variable of `groupid`.  Here is my code in the Web Service:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string GetRoomDataAttributes()
{
  if (Session["groupid"] != null)//always has no value?
   {
      string session_groupid = HttpContext.Current.Session["groupid"] as string;// *** edit: this should have the value of 1
   }

}
```

In the above code, there is indeed a key of 'groupid' in the Session object but it has no values; it should have 1 as the value. What is bugging me is that the value is not null yet has no actual data.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: where are you calling / consuming or creating the instance to the web service..? can you confirm that you are even able to step into the web service code..? also I would recommend changing `Session["groupid"] = 1;` to use `HttpContext.Current.Session["groupid"] = 1` and initialize that in the global.asax OnSessionStart method. can you provide more relevant code as well. show in your code where you are calling `GetRoomDataAttributes()`

Comment: Yes, I can step through the Web Service code and that's why it is not showing as null. Basically, I use the Ajax method through a standard html button which calls the .asmx web service and then I am able to step through. Before that, IF I press an ASP.NET button to set the session manually then only then the Web Service's Session variable is not null.

Comment: I think that you need to create a property inside of the Web Service and then when you create the instance to the web service , assign that property value which has been initialized meaning the Session variable. that would be a simple fix in my opinion

Comment: @Meengla What do you mean "value is not null yet has no actual data."? If it is not `null` it should have some value - any chance you are writing something else under the same key too?

Comment: Alexei: Yes, that's what I mean: in the 'Keys' of the session object I see a key name groupid but that, when assigned to a string variable, is null.

Comment: MethodMan: Could you elaborate how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you try to parse an `int` value (1) to a `string` using the `as` operator.

In fact what you were asking was: set `session_id` to the session variable `group_id` *if it is a string*. Well, that will never be true, since it is an `int`.

You can assign it to a `int?` directly since it casts `null` values correctly:

```
int? session_groupid = (int?)HttpContext.Current.Session["groupid"];
```

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, I had given my own Answer just before your's. Still you have given an explanation. I appreciate that. My problem was that in the debugger I did not see any value for the groupid key. So I just tried to assign that to a string variable and then use in SQL; but that string variable was always null.

Comment: I know. You knew how to fix it but not why it didn't work. Hope I clarified that.

Comment: Yes. Okay, if you will: So what is your code doing? I don't quite understand? Is it casting the session variable to an Int type? What is the 'int?' in the beginning of the expression? Thanks.

Comment: It is a nullable version of the `int` type. You could use `as` here too, but you shouldn't since you know the type at hand. Since `int` can't be null, you need `int?` which can.

Comment: Thanks. But what is it doing here? I mean the !null was passed and why couldn't I cast the groupid as int--which I did try but didn't work. So want to understand what is the nullable version of int doing here?

Comment: It directly casts the value in the session variable to an int, which can be null in the case the variable wasn't filled.

Comment: Final question :) So if int? does come to being null it would mean, somehow, the session lost the value of the groupid? If so then in the subsequent code I should try to catch that?

Comment: Yes. Server rebooted. Maybe you reset it somewhere else. Always check the field not to be null.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again! I am done in this thread. I wish you had looked the code above--I just chanced upon the Answer by reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service

Answer (score 0):

The ASMX service and the ASP.NET page are not actually using the same session - that is why the value is not being carried over from one to the other.

When you connect to the web service you should make sure that your web service client is passing in the session token from ASPX to ASMX as well.

Comment: I wanted to avoid carrying the session's group id in the default.aspx page; this is just a test page; the final call will come from a javascript .js file--which would first call another function to establish login credentials in session.

Comment: So this javascript file - is it independently establishing credentials for both the web service and the asp page? Is the authentication mechanism equivalent for both systems?

Comment: Currently there is no javascript file. The default.aspx document is a test page which is manually establishing session credentials. The final page will be an .aspx page, holding mostly javascript code. Some of that code will present a login box and pass the data to the Web Service which would establish the credentials in the session object. And, yes, authentication would be the same.

Comment: Slightly modified the Question to show the string variable--which doesnt get the value of 1

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem in establishing my session variables and making the Web service to recognize the session's key's values. I think my problem was trying to parse the value. Here is I ended up doing the parsing:

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Session["groupid"] != null)
  {
    int? session_groupid = (int?)Session["groupid"];
  }
```

Pretty frustrating to figure this out but learned some new things. Thank you all for the help!

HTH.